# Can an unfinished Integrated Master’s qualify for an H-1B?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, visa

I’m at the last year of an integrated Master’s degree in the UK.

This means that if this was a normal degree, I would have earned a bachelor’s at the end of last year.

Because it’s integrated, I *think* that means I currently hold no official qualifications, and will only hold a Master’s when I complete this degree this year.

Am I able to start the application for an H-1B now, or would I have to wait until I get that Master’s?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Expatriates Stack Exchange.

Comment: @nij or maybe academia.stackexchange.com in terms of whether they can claim a bachelors if you dont finish the masters.  to be honest sounds like a question for the university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have actually been awarded a Bachelor's degree (which didn't happen to my friends at Cambridge or my son at Southampton), you are still an undergraduate.  As such, you need to complete the degree first.